# kafka is not available inside docker - windows - jhipster

Tags: windows, docker, apache-kafka, jhipster

I've generated a jhipster application with kafka. I started kafka.yml with docker-compose and when I start the application I get the following error

> org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to
>   start bean
>   'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry';
>   nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException:
>   Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata

kafka.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.3.0
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.3.0
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 2
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
```

docker-compose output:

```
docker-compose -f kafka.yml up -d
docker_kafka_1 is up-to-date
docker_zookeeper_1 is up-to-date
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think root of your issue is JHipster app and Kafka are not in the same docker network. So to achieve that one way I know is to have one `docker-compose.yml` with both app and Kafka configs in it. You also may consider import/include configs from `app.yml` and `kafka.yml` to it to avoid duplication.